# How do you calculate acceleration with mass and a force?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces

So my physics class is going over Energy and force and we had to solve a problem where we found acceleration with only force and mass how do we do that

Comment: That should have been the very first equation you learned the first time the word "force" was used in your class.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:quantum-mechanics]?  Are you asking about the classical $a=\frac{F}{m}$, or do you mean to ask about some sort of quantum analog, or...?

Answer (score 1):

$\vec{F} = m \vec{a}$ for a constant mass, $m$.

This can be rearranged to $\vec{a} = \frac{\vec{F}}{m}$.